# Docker increase disk space

Tags: docker

I have a Docker container running but it's giving me a disk space warning.  How can I increase the container's space and start again? (The same container)

Let's say I want to give like 15gb.

Comment: What's the disk space error you're getting? More likely you've run out of space on the docker host machine.

Comment: Regular docker itself (running the basic OSS component natively on Linux and ignoring extra optional components like `docker-machine`) doesn't impose disk space limits at all in the first place unless it's explicitly asked to.

Answer (score 41):

You can also increase disk space through the docker GUI[image: Docker GUI (Mac)]

Comment: If you're using the Windows Subsystem for Linux, you need to use the .wslconfig file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configure-global-options-with-wslconfig

Comment: This answer is platform-specific (the screenshots are from Mac, in this case) and don't apply everywhere Docker runs.

Answer (score 19):

I assume you are talking about disk space to run your containers.

Make sure that you have enough space on whatever disk drive you are using for `/var/lib/docker` which is the default used by Docker.  You can change it with the `-g` daemon option.

If you don't have enough space you may have to repartition your OS drives so that you have over 15GB.  If you are using `boot2docker` or `docker-machine` you will have to grow the volume on your Virtual Machine. It will vary depending on what you are using for Virtualization (i.e VirtualBox, VMware, etc)

For example if you are using VirtualBox and `docker-machine` you can start with something like this for a 40GB VM.

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size "40000" default
```

Comment: correction: docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size "100000" default

Answer (score 5):

I ran into similar problem with my docker-vm (which is 'alpine-linux' on VMware Fusion in OS X):

```
 write error: no space left on device alpinevm:/mnt/hgfs
 failed to build: .. no space left on device
```

.. eventually [this guide helped](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/ayzdpr/expanding_disk_in_alpine_linux/) me to resize/expand my docker volume.

TL;DR:

1 - Check size of partition containing **/var/lib/docker**

```
> df -h
/dev/sda3                17.6G      4.1G     12.6G  25% /var/lib/docker
```

look for '/dev/sdaN', where N is your partition for '/var/lib/docker', in my case **/dev/sda3**

2 - Shut down your VM, open VM Settings > Hard Disk(s) > change size of your 'virtual_disk.vmdk' (or whatever is your machine's virtual disk), then click Apply ([see this guide](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1020778)).

3 - Install **cfdisk** and **e2fsprogs-extra** which contains **resize2fs**

```
> apk add cfdisk
> apk add e2fsprogs-extra
```

4 - Run **cfdisk** and resize/expand **/dev/sda3**

```
> cfdisk
Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size  Id Type

/dev/sda1  *        2048    206847    204800   100M  83 Linux
/dev/sda2         206848   4241407   4034560   1.9G  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3        4241408  83886079  79644672  12.6G  83 Linux

[Bootable]  [ Delete ]  [ Resize ]  [  Quit  ]  [  Type  ]  [  Help  ]  [  Write ]  [  Dump  ]
```

.. press down/up to select '/dev/sda3'

.. press left/right/enter to select 'Resize' -> 'Write' -> 'Quit'

5 - Run **resize2fs** to expand the file system of **/dev/sda3**

```
> resize2fs /dev/sda3
```

6 - Verify resized volume

```
> df -h
/dev/sda3                37.3G      4.1G     31.4G  12% /var/lib/docker
```

Comment: Are all these commands being run in host system (what OS is that), how would it convert to a windows host?

Answer (score 1):

To increase space available for Docker you will have to increase your docker-pool size. If you do a

```
lvs
```

You will see the docker-pool logical volume and its size. If your docker pool is sitting on a volume group that has free space you can simply increase the docker-pool LV by

```
lvextend -l 100%FREE <path_to_lv>
# An example using this may looks like this:
# lvextend -l 100%FREE /dev/VolGroup00/docker-pool
```

You can check out more docker diskspace tips [here](http://burhan.io/docker-hacks-for-production/)

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Docker stores all layers/images in its file formate (i.e. aufs) in default /var/lib/docker directory.

If you are getting disk space warning because of docker then there must of lot of docker images and you need to clean up it.

If you have option to add disk space then can you create separate partition with bigger size and mount your /var/lib/docker over there which will help you to get rid of filling root partition.

some extra information can be found here  on managing disk space for docker .
http://www.scmtechblog.net/2016/06/clean-up-docker-images-from-local-to.html