# TensorFlow with Docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I've created a Docker machine to run TensorFlow:

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox tensorflow
$ eval $(docker-machine env tensorflow)
$ docker-machine ls
NAME               ACTIVE   URL          STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS  
tensorflow   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://193.168.99.101:2376           v1.9.1
```

Then I try to launch a container with the TesnorFlow dev image:

```
$ docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
```

But I get the following printout and error:

```
Unable to find image 'b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel' locally
latest-devel: Pulling from tensorflow/tensorflow
d5abe3500fe7: Verifying Checksum 
b4906bf7cb96: Download complete 
bfd1864b7d78: Verifying Checksum 
b5834ff0edff: Download complete 
37c70795c272: Download complete 
fd1295db72c3: Verifying Checksum 
0851dd369c75: Download complete 
f090bc83193e: Download complete 
3505c3e79922: Download complete 
5f7f94f4a89a: Download complete 
82d880401459: Download complete 
3f8ab9378c1a: Verifying Checksum 
cd2e7af6dd36: Verifying Checksum 
0fbd1aaa7f93: Download complete 
a073e9eadc31: Verifying Checksum 
eac8972ce5cd: Download complete 
d20000bda44f: Download complete 
7abc7a47a494: Download complete 
6a90f0a0e005: Download complete 
Pulling repository b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
74c849ee103e: Error pulling image (latest-devel) from b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow, Untar re-exec error: exit status 1: output: write /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libitm.a: no space left on device bitm.a: no space left on device 
a82f81f25750: Download complete 
b207c06aba70: Download complete 
d55e68e6cc9c: Download complete 
0aa714ad37e0: Download complete 
28f77615a692: Error downloading dependent layers 
Error pulling image (latest-devel) from b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow, Untar re-exec error: exit status 1: output: write /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libitm.a: no space left on device
```

I'm not sure what to do here... **Will someone explain what this means and how I should proceed?**

Extra info: I'm on Mac OSX 10.9,

```
$ docker info
Containers: 0
Images: 12
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: tmpfs
 Dirs: 12
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 4.1.13-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.9.1 (TCL 6.4.1); master : cef800b - Fri Nov 20 19:33:59 UTC 2015
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 996.2 MiB
Name: tensorflow
Debug mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 11
 Goroutines: 19
 System Time: 2016-01-24T02:54:29.677797424Z
 EventsListeners: 0
 Init SHA1: 
 Init Path: /usr/local/bin/docker
 Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
```

Comment: You need a larger space allocated to the docker container.

Comment: The output indicates you're out of disk space. Either your VM lacks disk space, or your computer itself is out of disk space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the default docker create, try this:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size "20000" tensorflow
```

Then:

```
eval $(docker-machine env tensorflow)
docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
```

**Note**:

- See [Docker increase disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485723/docker-increase-disk-space)
- Make sure you have 20 GB on your physical disk