# How can I fix Docker/Mac no space left on device error?

Tags: macos, docker

I have built a pretty big image (1G) that has a lot of "infrastructure" in it for testing (Mongo, Kafka, etc.)

When trying to start this I get no space left on device errors.  How can I fix this?

I've cleaned off stopped images and removed any images I don't absolutely need.

Answer (score 143):

If you get `no space left on device` error with Docker, you might be able to solve this easily with `system prune`.

I use Docker for Mac 17.03.

With docker UP and all your containers RUNNING, execute `docker system prune -a`

This should give the following dialog:

```
WARNING! This will remove:
- all stopped containers
- all volumes not used by at least one container
- all networks not used by at least one container
- all images without at least one container associated to them Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]
```

Then press y to delete lots of containers, concluding (in my case) with: `Total reclaimed space: 23.26 GB.`

Now you can go back to work without even rebooting docker!

Comment: This is a solution, can't imagine how increasing disk allocation could be a solution once it still leaves all those trash files there.

Answer (score 126):

You can resize the virtual disk image size in Docker for Mac's Preferences in the *Disk* tab. This will increase the space **without data loss**.

---

In newer versions, the settings can be found in the *Resources* tab (sub-tab *"Advanced"*):
[image: Option name: Disk image size]

Comment: It depends, at some point your real disk will be full and increasing the virtual disk is not an option anymore :-)

Comment: I also think this should be the correct answer now.

Comment: I agree that this should be the accepted answer as well. My use-case, I don't want to delete all my build cache as I was trying to re-work my Dockerfile so cacheable steps would not be invalidated.

Comment: In my case I had to go to Resources tab and Advanced section to change these. My Docker for Mac Community version 4.1.7

Comment: I did this and the Docker.raw file did get smaller, but I never got the space back when going to About this Mac > Storage.  I shrank the disk image size from 64GB to 8GB but the space didn't show up as being reclaimed in Storage.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well, just increased my disk space to 256 GB.... Don't worry, disk space is cheap they said...  This is not a solution.

Answer (score 15):

Check your directories of docker to locate your problem (on MAC this will be different but the same approach could help)

```
du -hs /var/lib/docker
```

You're able to see which folder is taking a lot of disk space by performing the same command on subfolders of `/var/lib/docker` :

- For `/var/lib/docker/volumes`: You have to delete '[orphaned](http://container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker/)' volumes.
  You can also use `docker volume ls -qf dangling=true` to check the
  volumes. To delete the orphaned volumes: `docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)`
- For `/var/lib/docker/containers` you have to check if you have a lot of stopped (or running) containers with `docker ps` = running containers and `docker ps -a` = all containers (running and stopped). To delete stopped containers: `docker rm -v $(docker ps -aq)`. The `-v` flag will automatically delete the volume of the container
- For `/var/lib/docker/images` you can delete all your unused images by using `docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)`

Also check GitHub to find some very useful scripts which delete you unused images/containers/volumes.

Comment: $ du -hs /var/lib/docker
du: /var/lib/docker: No such file or directory

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532483/where-is-var-lib-docker-on-mac-os-x for finding /var/lib/docker on mac

Answer (score 9):

Try increasing your disk space.  This is what worked for me.
Docker -> preferences -> disk -> Disk image size (increase it) -> Apply

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer, before just `system prune` everything.

Comment: I did not know this.  I wonder why docker doesn't provide a cli-way of doing this rather than a UI way.

Answer (score 3):

You can update size of a hard drive available for vm in
`$HOME/.docker/machine/machines/default/config.json`

Comment: You should tell us what one has to change, not just which file the change is in.

Answer (score 2):

You can click on the Docker icon at the top, then `preferences`. Go to the `reset` tab and click on `remove all data`.

Comment: As of 2021 this no longer seems to be an option in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can always drop and recreate the boot2docker vm anew to make sure only the needed images/containers are built/imported anew. If you keep hitting the space issue you might want to give your boot2docker vm bit more space, see [Docker increase disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485723/docker-increase-disk-space)

Answer (score 0):

In Docker version 4.28.0, navigate to `Settings > Resources`. Right under the section for Virtual Disk Limit, you'll find `Disk Image Location`. Copy that line and run the following command to check the volume used.

```bash
% du -hs /Users/tatsuya.suzuki/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data
 83G    /Users/tatsuya.suzuki/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data
```

[image]